# Image slider performance

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, slider

i was testing some image sliders written with javascript and i thought i could use them instead of coding it from the scratch.

If it comes to a big amount of images (400) it is just horrible slow. I did some testing with firefox developer tools and the network monitor shows that e.g. 5 images are loading within 10-15 ms and then others with 300 - 600ms. Its totally random. All images are nearly the same size.
Overall it is taken over a minute to load 80MB. Tested in a local environment.

Any ideas without seeing some code?

Comment: Is the size of each image web save?

Comment: 400 images... Is a lot! Please consider another option. Something with preloading maybe?

Comment: yes, of course something with preloading to prevent this. I am still confused why the speed of every image is so randomly different. @gerton yes, every image is web save.

Comment: What you could try is load the images in after the page is already loaded with Ajax?